# Working with PIX firewalls

Tags: cisco, cisco-pix

I have acquired a used Pix firewall. A PIX 506 to use as a firewall for my small home office, the netgear wi-fi was really not cutting it.

I'd like to get a pointer on where to start with it, like how do I reset it to factory specs,  log in, etc.

I'm an OS X, Linux, UNIX person and don't know IOS or Windows.

Comment: Cisco has documents on how to do factory resets: http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/vpndevc/ps2030/products_password_recovery09186a008009478b.shtml

Comment: Be very careful with that device. The PIX line is end-of-life/end-of-support/end-of-patch with known vulnerabilities with public exploits. Particularly the 501/506 since they only support up to 6.3. You would be better served with a 2000 era PC running pfSense or something similar.

Comment: @ScottPack -- I actually also have a PIX 515, is that any better?

Comment: @user1172468 The 515e is the bottom grade, but most modern class, of PIXes. It'll take the newest PIXOS but is still abandoned technology. So better, but still a bit scary. That device does use standard desktop RAM, I can't remember which exactly, so it is easy to upgrade out of support.

Comment: @ScottPack, mmm I like pfSense but I really want a low power consumption system ... so I thought the PIXes would fit the bill ... so a 515e is scary ?

Comment: The entire PIX line is dead now, the 515e just supports a newer revision than the 506. Don't forget, the 515e bottom vents, so don't put it on a shelf.

Answer (score 1):

Running the startup wizard if available in the OS you're running might be your best bet to start.

Comment: Hi Keith, I have access to Linux and OS X -- is there a start up wizard for these two OSes?

Comment: If you have the serial cable to match you can connect it.  9600 N/8/1 is the default connection.  Boot it to see what OS you are running.  Then you can run the factory reset procedure detailed in the other posts.  At that point you may have a startup wizard available when you reboot.

Answer (score 1):

Password reset can be found on the Cisco site -  http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/vpndevc/ps2030/products_password_recovery09186a008009478b.shtml

There is a quick start on the Cisco website - http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/pix/pix62/quick/guide/506quick.html

The web panel is Java based (If it is installed on your PIX) so will run on Windows, Linux, MAC.